# Adding session management to a API-Only Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a rails only API application. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z18zLCAg7UU&list=PLgYiyoyNPrv_yNp5Pzsx0A3gQ8-tfg66j) and it stated that creating an API only rails App would removed all the Session capabilities. I was wondering if I simply added all the [middleware for session management](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#other-middleware), would it contain all the Session capabilities of a regular rails application?